# Filter P4 .Net file list

Tags: c#, perforce, getfiles

I have a program that populates a combo box with details of files contained in a selected directory in a perforce depot.

The relevant piece of code is this:

```
PerforcePath dir = _ctlProductSelect.SelectedItem as PerforcePath;

_ctlServicePackSelect.Items.Clear();

if (dir != null)
{
    foreach (P4.File file in _perforce.GetFiles(null, P4.FileSpec.DepotSpec(dir.Path + "/*.sp")))
    {
       _ctlServicePackSelect.Items.Add(new PerforcePath(file.DepotPath.Path));
    }
}
```

The problem is that this also includes files that are marked as deleted. Is there any way I can filter the deleted files from the list returned by `GetFiles` method? I can't find any likely suspects in the P4_dotNet API documentation.

Comment: Did you try checking the `LocalPath` or `ClientPath` properties of the `File` object to see if the file is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Using P4API.NET, you can add the `-e` option to `GetFiles`:

```
IList filesToFind = new List();
FileSpec fileToFind = new FileSpec(new DepotPath("//depot/..."), null, null, VersionSpec.Head);
filesToFind.Add(fileToFind);
Options o = new Options();
o.Add("-e", "");
IList filesFound = pRep.GetFiles(filesToFind, o);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually got working was to do this inisde the foreach loop:

```
foreach (P4.File file in _perforce.GetFiles(null, P4.FileSpec.DepotSpec(dir.Path + "/*.sp")))
{
    if (_perforce.GetFileMetaData(null, file)[0].HeadAction.ToString() != "MoveDelete")
    _ctlServicePackSelect.Items.Add(new PerforcePath(file.DepotPath.Path));
}
```

basically checking the metadata for each file before adding it to the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<FileSpec> filesToFind = new List<FileSpec>();
FileSpec fileToFind = new FileSpec(FileSpec.DepotSpec("//depot/...").DepotPath, Revision.Head);
filesToFind.Add(fileToFind);
Options o = new Options();

o.Add("-m", "changelistid");
IList<File> FilesFound = rep.GetFiles(filesToFind, o)
```